# How to create sequence in C# form working with ArduinoDriver

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, embedded, arduino-ide

**Excuse me for my English**

In 2 days i will be showcasing my project on a big expo, but i ran into a few problems, hopefully you can help me!

My project will be a glass container with a solution that contains iron-particles. I have 2 big electromagnets connected to relays connected to a arduino that are suppose to go on at the right timing in sequence with the audiotrack using timestamps.

I am using:

- Arduino Uno R3
- 2 Relay module (http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino ... nel-Relay/)
- 2 electromagnets 50kg pulling-power 
  (https://www.aliexpress.com/item-img/XRN ... 14680.html)
- Adapter (12v 2,0A)

With this code 1 magnet goes on and the other goes off each 2 seconds, it works.

Code in Arduino IDE (C++)

```
int mag1 = 6;
int mag2 = 7;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //Selecteer magneten als output
  pinMode(mag1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mag2, OUTPUT);;

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
  mag1on();   
  delay(2000);
  mag2on();


}
//Magneet 1 aan
void mag1on(){

  digitalWrite(mag2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(mag1, HIGH); 

  }
//Magneet 2 aan
void mag2on(){

  digitalWrite(mag1, LOW);                       
  digitalWrite(mag2, HIGH); 

  }
```

My problem now is that i am trying to make a C# form where i have a start button and if you press the button the sequence on the arduino will have to start and the audio-file should play so the magnet-sequence and audio will play synchronically. I am trying to use the ArduinoDriver for .NET in visual studio so i can create the sequence in the form but i have absolutely no idea how to give commands to the arduino with this method. Please help me so that i can write a sequence in a C# form that makes magnet1 go on at 00:11 and magnet2 go on at 00:30 etc.

I hope i gave enough information, if not please ask me and i will react fast. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Take a look [at this tutorial](http://playground.arduino.cc/Csharp/SerialCommsCSharp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a small assumption that what you mean by c# form is a winform programmed in c#.

That said, I think you are missing a transport layer.
You first have to decide how you want to send the message from your device running the winform program, to your arduino device.

Simplicity and cost recommends you use a serial port cuz your uno has one built in and if your device running the c# app has one as well, some don't these days.

If not you can choose to go Ethernet, Bluetooth, or even port to port depending on what hardware your running on.

Then you can get into the details of how to get the application specific functions working.

You must first crawl, walk, run... in that order